# Don't want to use for loop in Pandas. How can I use Apply in this case?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I know that for loops is not a good thing in Pandas. `apply` could be better. But I found it is hard to use `apply` in my quesiton.

```
data = {'A':[1,1,1,2,2], 'B':[2018,2019,2020,2019,2020],'PR':[12,10,0,24,20],'WP':[300,0,0,300,0],'BD':[6,5,0,2,1],'i':[1,2,1,1,2],'r':[0.5,0.25,0,0.5,0.25]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['X'] = 0
df['Y'] = 0
df['Z'] = 0
```

The original dataframe:

[[image: the original dataframe]]

My aim is:

Divide the df to two groups, according to A.

For each group, calculate the X Y and Z

X = (Z in last year + PR in current year) * i in this year

Y = Z in last year + WP movement from last year to this year + BD movement from last year to this year + X in this year

Z = Y in this year * r in this year.

The following is my code, it works well. But I don't want to use for loop. Are there any better methods?

```
# divide the df to two groups
sub_df = [df[df['A'].isin([i])] for i in np.unique(df['A'])]

a = []
for df in sub_df:
    df = df.copy()
    df.loc[-1] = [0]*df.shape[1] #add a 0 row to calculate the first year.
    df.sort_index(inplace = True)
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    for n in range(1,df.shape[0]):
        df.loc[n,'X'] = (df.loc[n-1,'Z'] + df.loc[n,'PR']) * df.loc[n,'i']
        df.loc[n,'Y'] = df.loc[n-1,'Z'] + df.loc[n,'WP'] - df.loc[n-1,'WP'] + df.loc[n,'BD'] - df.loc[n-1,'BD'] + df.loc[n,'X']
        df.loc[n,'Z'] = df.loc[n,'Y'] *  df.loc[n,'r']
    a.append(df[1:])

b = pd.concat(a)
b
```

Comment: why are you doing a copy of df every iteration?

Comment: I am afraid that there could be a chained index warning. It works without this copy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any other method that isn't using for-loop, but I managed to simplify the code a little bit:

```py
def get_df(df):
    X, Y, Z = [], [], []
    prev_Z, prev_WP, prev_BD = 0, 0, 0

    for pr, i, wp, bd, r in zip(df["PR"], df["i"], df["WP"], df["BD"], df["r"]):
        X.append((prev_Z + pr) * i)
        Y.append(prev_Z + wp - prev_WP + bd - prev_BD + X[-1])
        Z.append(Y[-1] * r)
        prev_Z, prev_WP, prev_BD = Z[-1], wp, bd

    df["X"] = X
    df["Y"] = Y
    df["Z"] = Z

    return df


out = df.groupby("A").apply(get_df)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   A     B  PR   WP  BD  i     r      X      Y      Z
0  1  2018  12  300   6  1  0.50   12.0  318.0  159.0
1  1  2019  10    0   5  2  0.25  338.0  196.0   49.0
2  1  2020   0    0   0  1  0.00   49.0   93.0    0.0
3  2  2019  24  300   2  1  0.50   24.0  326.0  163.0
4  2  2020  20    0   1  2  0.25  366.0  228.0   57.0
```

according my timing, your code takes `0.004833603044971824` seconds to complete, my version `0.0019200179958716035` seconds, so ~2.5x faster.

Comment: The Prints is correct. It is really helpful.